# pygame.mixer.music plays audio fine but pygame.mixer.Sound gives error 'Unable to open file'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, mixer

I have a simple code in which i want to play an audio file using pygame's mixer class. When I do:

```
import pygame

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(dir_path, "mp3s", 'info.mp3')

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(path)
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

it works just fine. But when I try the same with:

```
import pygame

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(dir_path, "mp3s", 'info.mp3')

pygame.mixer.init()
mysound = pygame.mixer.Sound(file=path)
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(mysound)
```

It gives error `Unable to open file '/home/pi/myproject/mp3s/info.mp3'`

I've tried googling and only thing I could find was either to try `pygame.init()` or `pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))` neither of which worked for me... Any ideas on what might be wrong? I'm using Raspberry Pi with Raspbian installed and python 3.7 with pygame 1.9.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `Sound` class for `mp3` playback, as it only supports `ogg` and `wav`.

See the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound) of `pygame.mixer.Sound`:

> The Sound can be loaded from an OGG audio file or from an uncompressed WAV.

The only way to play a `mp3` file with pygame is to use `pygame.mixer.music`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394523/should-tag-mantissa-an-application-server-built-on-twisted-and-axiom-be-dele